# about react native flex,text nesting view,error

Tags: react-native

How to make the text display from the position marked red？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hOdC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty space for that, like this 

`<Text>{'This is first line text'}<Text>{'  this is second line text'}</Text></Text>`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. There will be compatibility problems with spaces.